# Google Cloud Vision API Text Detection Detecting Wrong Language

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-vision

I have an image in Syriac that I would like detected:

[image]

The text in the image is "ܒܒܐ", my code for running the text detection is as follows:

```html
const vision = require('@google-cloud/vision');
const client = new vision.ImageAnnotatorClient();

const fileName = 'baba.jpg';

// Read a local image as a text document
const [result] = await client.textDetection(fileName);
const fullTextAnnotation = result.fullTextAnnotation;
console.log(`Full text: ${fullTextAnnotation.text}`);
fullTextAnnotation.pages.forEach(page => {
  page.blocks.forEach(block => {
    console.log(`Block confidence: ${block.confidence}`);
    block.paragraphs.forEach(paragraph => {
      console.log(`Paragraph confidence: ${paragraph.confidence}`);
      paragraph.words.forEach(word => {
        const wordText = word.symbols.map(s => s.text).join('');
        console.log(`Word text: ${wordText}`);
        console.log(`Word confidence: ${word.confidence}`);
        word.symbols.forEach(symbol => {
          console.log(`Symbol text: ${symbol.text}`);
          console.log(`Symbol confidence: ${symbol.confidence}`);
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

However, my result ends up as detecting the image as "27-" instead of "ܒܒܐ"

Comment: Syriac is not yet supported by Vision API as of now https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/languages . You can open a [feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list) to include this on their supported language.